# how to grep for the first instance of the pattern among multiple patterns

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have three different patterns and I want to find the out which patters appeared first in the file and which parrent appear last in the file and I need to print the lines also which contains the first and last pattern.

I treid below grep but its applicable only to one pattern.  I think once its figured out how to find the rank of patterns then printing of last patter could be done by same logic by using "tac".

```
grep -m 1 "pattern1" test.txt
```

my three patterns are

```
1.PATTERN1  
2.PATTERN2  
3.PATTERN3  

Line1 this is a sample line for example without  any meaning please ignore
Line2 only meant for giving an example PATTERN2 to make my query clear to all
Line3 this is a sample line for example without  any meaning please ignore
Line4 only meant for giving an example pattern1 to make my query clear to all
Line5 this is a sample line for example without  any meaning please ignore
Line6 only meant for giving an example pattern1 to make my query clear to all
Line7 this is a sample line for example without  any meaning please ignore
Line8 only meant for giving an example pattern2 to make my query clear to all
Line9 this is a sample line for example without  any meaning please ignore
Line10 only meant for giving an example pattern3 to make my query clear to all
Line11 only meant for giving an example pattern1 to make my query clear to all
```

I want to print the line containg the first occarance of any patterns among PATTERN1,PATTERN2, PATTERN3.

**So desired output should be :**

```
First pattern among the three
-------------------------------
Line2 only meant for giving an example PATTERN2 to make my query clear to all

Last instance amoung the three:
-------------------------------
Line11 only meant for giving an example pattern1 to make my query clear to all
```

Comment: Can you post some sample input and desired output? It will be more clear what you exactly want to do.

Comment: Tried to clear my thoughts ,please have a look now

Comment: Great, now it is very clear. I formatted the text a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say:

```
grep -E -m1 "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3" test.txt
```

This would print the first line matching either `pattern1`, `pattern2` or `pattern3`.

As you mentioned, you could use `tac` to find the last matching pattern in the file:

```
grep -E -m1 "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3" <(tac test.txt)
```

---

In case, you version of `grep` doesn't support `-E`, you could say:

```
grep -m1 "pattern1\|pattern2\|pattern3" test.txt
```

---

EDIT: In order to find only the first and line line matching any pattern, you could say:

```
grep "pattern1\|pattern2\|pattern3" test.txt | sed -n '1p;$p'
```

(Use the `-i` option for `grep` if you want to perform case-insensitive matches.)

Comment: Thanks,how can I feed this output of grep to sed commands if I want to delete everything about the first pattern ?

Comment: @user2809888 Pipe to sed.  `| sed '/PATTERN1/d'`

Comment: I don't know which pattern would be first pattern ,this is decided by grep's output. I need to write it so sed would take whatever output comes from grep/

Comment: more details, suppose I want to delete everything above PATTERN2's first occarance and pattern1 last occarance. wondring even if its possible.Pattern2 and PATTERN1 are decided by the output og grep command.

Comment: Please, please, post a new question if you have questions that aren't related to the new one.  Or edit your current question if you think otherwise.  Communicating via comments isn't really helpful for those who come over looking for similar issues.

Comment: I agree, I will post new question. I am new to here so probably not familar with etiquettes.

Comment: @user2809888 Let me add that if you remotely feel that you have a new question, post another one instead of editing.

Comment: @user2809888 Do you remember that for this question you were asked to provide sample data as an example in order to make it clear.  Don't forget it do the same for your next question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop instead of the grep -E construct alone. With grep -m1, only the first match is returned for each pattern. The -i option was added to ignore case, otherwise only exact matches are shown.

```
for i in PATTERN1 PATTERN2 PATTERN3; do grep -i $i -m1 test.txt; done
```

This produces the following results...

```
Line4 only meant for giving an example pattern1 to make my query clear to all
Line2 only meant for giving an example PATTERN2 to make my query clear to all
Line10 only meant for giving an example pattern3 to make my query clear to all
```